# How do I parse an HTML response to JSON by using X-Path?

Tags: android, json, api, web-services, android-json

I am getting a ***HTML*** response from `HTTPGET` method. How do I parse that ***html*** response to JSON?

Which API do I use to parse it?
I also want to know what is the main use of `x-path`.
HTML Response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie ie8 lt-ie9 lt-ie10"> <![endif]> <[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie ie9 lt-ie10"> <![endif]> <if IE]> <html lang="en" class="ie"> <![endif] <[if gt IE 9]> <html lang="en"> <![endif] <head prefix="og: ogp.me/ns# fb: ogp.me/ns/fb# snapdeallog:#"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="i1.sdlcdn.com"; />
```

Comment: What does your HTML response look like ?

Comment: It looks like :<!DOCTYPE html>
<[if IE 8]>
<html lang="en" class="ie ie8 lt-ie9 lt-ie10">
    <![endif]>
    <[if IE 9]>
    <html lang="en" class="ie ie9 lt-ie10">
        <![endif]>
        <if IE]>
        <html lang="en" class="ie">
            <![endif]
            <[if gt IE 9]>
            
            <html lang="en">
                
                <![endif]
                <head prefix="og: https://ogp.me/ns# fb: https://ogp.me/ns/fb# snapdeallog:#">
                    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://i1.sdlcdn.com" />

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/download) as a tool to convert your HTML to JSON.

```
final String HTML = "<!DOCTYPE html> <[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie ie8 lt-ie9 lt-ie10"> <![endif]> <[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie ie9 lt-ie10"> <![endif]> <if IE]> <html lang="en" class="ie"> <![endif] <[if gt IE 9]> <html lang="en"> <![endif] <head prefix="og: ogp.me/ns# fb: ogp.me/ns/fb# snapdeallog:#"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="i1.sdlcdn.com"; />";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(HTML);
Element element = document.select("ANY HTML TAG").first();
String arrayName = element.select("TAG2").first().text();
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
Elements ie = element.getElementsByClass("ie");
Elements ei9 = element.getElementsByClass("ei9");
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
for (int i = 0, l = ie.size(); i < l; i++) {
    String key = ie.get(i).text();
    String value = ei9.get(i).text();
    jobj.put(key, value);
}
jsonArr.put(jobj);
jsonObj.put(arrayName, jsonArr);
System.out.println(jsonObj.toString());
```